# Conflicting rewrite rules htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these two rules next to each other

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ category-groups.php?furl=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+)?$ product.php?id=$2&head=$1 [QSA]
```

This works

```
/category-groups.php?furl=my-category-page
redirects to
/my-category-page
```

This doesn't work

```
/product.php?id=100&head=this-product
does not redirect to
/this-product-100
```

The product.php page is actually bounced to the category-groups.php page.

I hope that makes sense. I've tried many things but can't figure out to solve it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of your rules and make the regex match numbers:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+)?$ product.php?id=$2&head=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ category-groups.php?furl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

otherwise `^([^/\.]+)?$` will always just match everything.

Comment: That did it. Seems pretty logical. Thank you